# What is a beacon?

Tags: scandinavian-languages

I'm reading George W. DaSent's 1861 translation of *The Story of Burnt Njal* ([because it's available for free online](http://sagadb.org/brennu-njals_saga.en)). I have what some may consider a basic question, but given that I don't know anything about Iceland I thought I would ask it. What exactly is a beacon?

> Now both sides ride home from the Thing, and Hauskuld and Hrut ride westward by Hallbjorn's beacon.

I would appreciate answers that go into a little bit of depth about the cultural context of beacons in Iceland at the time period of the story.

Comment: Whether or not you think [tag:icelandic-sagas] are worth their own tag, this should definitely have the [tag:scandinavian-literature] tag, by our general consensus on using language tags.

Answer (score 6):

### It's a geographical feature: a stony hill with a cairn.

A [beacon](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beacon) doesn't have to be a man-made signal: the word can mean just a "high hill or other easily distinguishable object", e.g. one which can act as a landmark and provide guidance for sailors or wanderers. See, for instance, the [Brecon Beacons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brecon_Beacons).

I searched for "Hallbjorn's beacon" on Google; most of the results were from the Story of Burnt Njals, but I also found the following result from [*The book of the settlement of Iceland*](http://baekur.is/en/bok/000233832/0/144/The_book_of_the_settlement_of), which apparently describes the history of how these specific hills, or the cairns on them, came to be called Hallbjorn's beacons (emphasis mine):

> Snæbjorn   and  his  men   came   up  with  them   at  **the  hills  which   now   are   called   Hallbjorn's-Beacons**.      Hallbjorn      and  his  went  to  the  top  of  one   of  the   hills  and  defended  themselves  there;  there  three  of  Snæbjorn's  men  fell  and  both  Hallbjorn's  companions  ;  next   Snæbjorn  cut  off  the  foot    of   Hallbjorn    at   the   anckle   joint,   whereupon    he   limped   to  the  southermost   hill  and   slew   there  yet   two   men    of    Snæbjorn's   and    there    Hallbjorn    fell   withal;   therefore  **there  are  three  beacons   on  that  hill  but  five  on  the   other.**

It seems like the first "beacons" in this passage is used to mean the hills themselves, and the second is used to mean the cairns on top of the hills.

Now let's look at the [original Icelandic version](http://sagadb.org/brennu-njals_saga.is) of the story. (I say "original" - of course the *original* original was in Old Norse, but Icelandic is by far the closest of the modern Scandinavian languages to Old Norse, so this should be close enough. If anyone has the text of the story in Old Norse, let me know what the relevant paragraph says there.) The corresponding sentence is:

> Nú ríða þeir heim af þingi hvorirtveggju og ríða þeir vestur hjá Hallbjarnarvörðum.

(For the record, the translation you quote in your question seems pretty accurate. Even without knowing Icelandic, you can see that a word-for-word translation would be something like "Now ride they home from the Thing, both sides, and ride they west past Hallbjarn's beacon.")

So the original word is **Hallbjarnarvörðum**. Plugging this into an automatic translator, and adding spaces appropriately, gives something like "Hallbjarn guards" or "Hallbjarnar watches" or "Hallbjorn beacon". Searching Google for "Hallbjarnarvörðum" reveals that **it's a real place in Iceland**:

[image: Photograph]

[This page](http://www.nat.is/travelguide/ahugav_st_hallbjarnarvordur.htm) (in Icelandic) recounts the same story of Snæbjorn and Hallbjorn as cited above, explaining the history of the name; the same story is also available in what seems to be a fuller and more original form [here](https://is.wikisource.org/wiki/Landn%C3%A1mab%C3%B3k/51._kafli) (also in Icelandic). The [Iceland Road Guide](http://icelandroadguide.com/index.php?POI_G=c7e172b4-492e-4937-bfa9-81f63d1666a6&tqlPOI_G=c7e172b4-492e-4937-bfa9-81f63d1666a6&cmsszd=places&cmsszs=en) describes the Hallbjarnarvörður as "**stony mounds with cairns on them**", and [Map Carta](https://mapcarta.com/32906356) also describes it as a cairn in West Iceland. You can see the cairns on top of the stony mound in the photo above.

Comment: I can add that my modern Swedish translation leaves "Hallbjarnarvörður" untranslated, likely to enforce that it is a proper name (I suspect "Hallbjarnarvörðum" is a declined form).

Comment: @andejons Interpreted as a common noun, “Hallbjarnarvörðum” would be something like “to watchmen (*[vörður](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/v%C3%B6r%C3%B0ur)*, dative indefinite plural) of a bear (*[björn](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bj%C3%B6rn#Icelandic)*, genitive indefinite singular) of rocks (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/h%C3%B6ll#Icelandic)”. But in fact I think here the rocks are a coincidence, Hallbjörn/Hallbjorn is just somebody's name, and that's a place where people can guard or watch and that's named after him. Possibly, in fact, the place he guarded in that specific event.

Comment: “vörðum" is an indefinite plural (i.e. closer to “some watchers” than to “the watchers”). I'm curious what that entails.

Comment: @Gilles: the answer already gives the interpretation "Hallbjörn's beacons".  The dative is required by the preposition "hjá" in Icelandic (according to Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icelandic_grammar), and thus the name is most likely the "Hallbjarnarvörður" I found in my translation.